# Multiple push to remote branch without conflict

Tags: git, github

In github repo I have 'n' number of files namely file_1.txt, file_2.txt, ..... file_n.txt.

For every file there is a file processor (proc_n) that when runs update the respective file, so proc_1 if running will update file_1.txt, proc_2 if running will update file_2.txt, proc_x if running will update file_x.txt and so on.

'm' number of processes runs simultaneously where m can be any where from 1 to n.
Every process needs to update data in respective file and will not touch any other file.

What is the best way to push changes to repo without failure by running commands from within the process.
I tried:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout branch_name
# make file_x changes
git add *
git commit -m "file_x updated"
git pull --rebase origin branch_name
git push -q HEAD:branch_name
```

But some of processes fails depending on the timing of push / pulls and I get errors that head has been moved. Because of some constraints I need to make it work in one attempt for all of the running processes.

Comment: You do not need `rebase`, just `pull` is enough.

Comment: @kosist Yes you are correct. Leaving that aside I still need to solve the issue in hand. Between Pull and Push, the remote might get updated by another process causing the push to fail.

Comment: Each process modifies its own file. So, there will be no `merge` conflicts. So if you will `pull` first, and then `push` - it should be enough.

Comment: Agree and I am doing that but i get the following error occasionally:
[[[[ "Failed to push some refs to '<repo-url>'.
hint: Updates were rejected because remote contains work that you do no have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes (e.g. git pull ...) before pushing again. See the note about fast-forwards in 'git push' --help' for details". ]]]]

Seems like a race condition among processes pushing. Thoughs.

Comment: Modify your script in a way then that when such error is received, one move `pull` should be done.